# Way to control WCF code generation for operation contracts for external service

Tags: .net, wcf, soap, wsdl

I have reference to the external SOAP service from .NET Framework library project. After updating service reference in Visual Studio 2019 (16.11.5), it start generating `OperationContract` attributes with `IsOneWay=true`.

```
[System.ServiceModel.OperationContractAttribute
(IsOneWay=true, Action="http://sap.com/xi/WebService/soap1.1")]
```

There is no related WSDL changes I could notice, only several new fields. Rolled back to old WSDL - still same thing.

Is there any way to control generation of OperationContractAttribute via config files or `svcutil`?

Comment: This should be the result of using the DataContractSerializer selected by default. To configure it manually, open the `Reference.svcmap` file on the client of the service and change `<Serializer>Auto</Serializer>` to `<Serializer>XmlSerializer</Serializer>`. This causes VS to stop generating message contracts.

Comment: Changed Serializer from `Auto` to `XmlSerializer` in `Reference.svcmap`, but OperationContract attrs are still generating with `IsOneWay=true`.

Comment: Why control its generation? You can look at this [Understanding Generated Client Code](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/feature-details/understanding-generated-client-code)

Comment: I understand the generated code, but also want to understand why it is changed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be changed according to the service:
Use the one-way design pattern:

- When the client must call operations and is not affected by the
  result of the operation at the operation level.
- When using the NetMsmqBinding or the MsmqIntegrationBinding class.
  (For more information about this scenario, see Queues in WCF.)

[One-Way Services](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/feature-details/one-way-services)
[OperationContractAttribute Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.servicemodel.operationcontractattribute?view=dotnet-plat-ext-6.0)

Comment: I've discovered that generated code was previously changed manually by another developer. So `svcutil` generate operation contract attributes with `IsOneWay=true` by default and this behaviour wasn't changed as I thought.